# Dynamic Query Builder in GCP Spanner

Tags: java, sql, google-cloud-platform, query-builder, google-cloud-spanner

I have a complex query that I want to build using the dynamic Query Builder, is there any dynamic query builder in GCP Spanner.

Example:

```
DeleteQuery query = new DeleteQuery("account a").addWhere("a.id > 666")
                                                .addWhere("a.creation_date > '2013-01-01'");
```

Something like this

Answer (score 1):

The [standard Java client library for Google Cloud Spanner](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/tree/master/google-cloud-spanner) does not contain any dynamic query builders.

You could however use [Google Cloud Spanner with Hibernate](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate), and then use the dynamic query builders available in Hibernate or any other framework supporting Hibernate and/or JPA.